# How to get the list of all sitecollections created in the last 24 hours and print out a custom web property name?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I need to get a list of all site collections in the last 24 hours, and print out a web property(if it exists).

I tried this

```
$Today = [DateTime]::Today
$Yesterday = $Today.AddDays(-1)
Get-SPSite -Limit All | where {$_.RootWeb.Created -ge $Yesterday -And $_.RootWeb.Created -lt $Today} | select Url, {$_.RootWeb.Created}, $_.RootWeb.AllProperties{"ClientCode"}
```

but got this error

Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '"ClientCode"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
... | select Url, @{Name='Created';Expression={$_.RootWeb.Created}},@{Name='ClientCode';Expression={$_.RootWeb.AllProperties['ClientCode']}}
```

Comment: Looks like there is an extra parenthesis at the end. it worked after I took it out. | select Url, @{Name='Created';Expression={$_.RootWeb.Created}},@{Name='ClientCode';Expression={$_.RootWeb.AllProperties['ClientCode']}}

Comment: Thanks @ShawnTorres, it is fixed now.